# Unwanted "warning" stops the loading of my Netlogo model when using the extraWidget extension

Tags: netlogo

Every time I attempt to load a Netlogo model that uses the extraWidget extension the loading stops and I receive a warning. The warning explains that the extraWidget extension was created with the Netlogo extension API 6.0 and the version of Netlogo I'm using is API 6.1. I must click 'Continue" each time to complete the loading.

Is there a way to remove this warning?

Thanks
Rudy

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately your options here aren't great.  There is no flag or configuration to have NetLogo skip the warning.

1. Downgrade to NetLogo 6.0.4.  This is easy to do, but you'll miss out on any 6.1.0 and 6.1.1 features/fixes.  You can get it at the NetLogo downloads page:  https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/download.shtml
2. Fork [the eXtraWidgets repository](https://github.com/CRESS-Surrey/eXtraWidgets) and update the NetLogo version it uses to 6.1.0 in order to build your own jar that won't cause the error to be thrown.  I believe [this is the line](https://github.com/CRESS-Surrey/eXtraWidgets/blob/master/xw/build.sbt#L23) that would need to be updated, but you'd also need to get the proper development tools (sbt and a Java 8 JDK) installed and figure out how to do the compile and packaging of the extension.

Comment: Hi Jasper, I was about downgrade to 6.0.4 when Nicolas swooped in to save the day. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

(eXtraWidgets author here)

I have updated the extension for NetLogo 6.1.1.

The release is [here](https://github.com/CRESS-Surrey/eXtraWidgets/releases/tag/v2.0.0-BETA5) if you want to give it a spin.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, your update works fine. If I run into any issues I'll definitely let you know. Thank you once again.